# Me da error en el paso "And" del feature

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Estoy enfrentando un problema en este desarrollo de pruebas automatizadas utilizando Java, Selenium y Cucumber. En particular, estoy experimentando dificultades con el paso "And" especifico en un archivo .feature durante la ejecución de mis pruebas.

El paso implica interactuar con un elemento de la pagina web, especificamente hacer clic en un hipervinculo.

Cuando ejecuto las pruebas

Este es el .feature

```
Feature: Navigation bar
    To see the subpages
    Without logging in
    I can click the navigation bar links
 
# Scenario Outline: I can access the subpages through the navigation bar
#     Given I navigate to www.freerangetesters.com
#     When I go to <section> using the navigation bar
#     Examples:
#         | section |
#         | Cursos | 
#         | Recursos | 
#         | Udemy | 
#         | Mentorías | 
#         | Blog | 
    
Scenario: Courses are presented correctly to potential customers
    Given I navigate to www.freerangetesters.com
    When I go to Cursos using the navigation bar
    And I select Fundamentos del Testing
    Then I select Introduccion al Testing de Software
```

Este es paginaCursos

```
package pages;
 
public class PaginaCursos extends BasePage {
 
    private String FundamentosDelTestingLink = "///h2[normalize-space()='Fundamentos del Testing' and @href]";
 
    public PaginaCursos() {
        super(driver);
    }
 
    public void clickFundamentosDelTestingLink() {
        clickElement(FundamentosDelTestingLink);
    }
 
}
```

Y este es el FreeRangeSteps

```
package steps;

import io.cucumber.java.en.*;
import pages.PaginaCursos;
import pages.PaginaFundamentosTesting;
import pages.PaginaPrincipal;
 
public class FreeRangeSteps {
 
    PaginaPrincipal landingPage = new PaginaPrincipal();
    PaginaCursos cursosPage = new PaginaCursos();
    PaginaFundamentosTesting fundamentosPage = new PaginaFundamentosTesting();
 
    @Given("I navigate to www.freerangetesters.com")
    public void iNavigateToFRT() {
        landingPage.navigateToFreeRangeTesters();
    }

    @When("I go to {word} using the navigation bar")
    public void navigationBarUse(String section) {
        landingPage.clickSectionNavigationBar(section);
    }

    @And("I select Fundamentos del Testing")
    public void navegarFundaTest(){
        cursosPage.clickFundamentosDelTestingLink();
    }


    @Then("I select Introduccion al Testing de Software")
    public void selectIntroTesting(){
        fundamentosPage.clickIntroTestingLink();
    }
}
```